# Set of idempotent elements closed under addition: prove $a+a = 0, ab=ba$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

The statement of the problem:

If $R$ is a ring and $a \in R$, $a$ is **idempotent** if $a^2 = a$. If the set of all idempotent elements of $R$ is closed under addition, prove that for any $x, y \in R$ we have $x+x = 0, \space xy = yx$. **Hint:** start with $(x+x)^2$ and $(x+y)^2$.

What's confusing me here is that the statement seems wrong, as I have no idea how to use the fact that the idempotent elements are closed under addition  to prove $x+x = 0$ or $xy = yx$ for **any** $x, y \in R$, but I can't seem to think of a counterexample. The only example where the set of idempotent elements is closed under addition that I could think of is $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, and the statement indeed holds for that ring. Is there a way to connect an arbitrary element of a ring with the idempotent ones, or is the statement of the problem wrong?

**P.S.** The statement is easy to prove if we add the requirement that $x, y$ are themselves idempotent: $(x+x)^2 = 4x^2 = 4x$, and since $x + x$ is also idempotent, $(x+x)^2 = x+x =2x$, so $4x = 2x$, so $x+x+x+x=x+x$, so $x+x=0$.

On the other hand, $(x+y)^2 = x + y = x^2+y^2+xy+yx=x+y+xy+yx$, so $xy+yx=0$, and I get stuck here again because $xy = -yx$, which isn't the same as $xy = yx$.

Comment: I think you should use the fact that 1 is an idempotent, and see where you can go from there.

Comment: Does "ring" mean "ring with 1" for you? Otherwise $2\Bbb Z$ is a counterexample

Comment: Yes, "ring" means "ring with 1" for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observation of the characteristic being $2$ is already well covered by Hagen von Eitzen's solution. This is to address the claim that the ring is also commutative.

> What's confusing me here is that the statement seems wrong, as I have no idea how to use the fact that the idempotent elements are closed under addition  to prove $x+x = 0$ or $xy = yx$ for **any** $x, y \in R$, but I can't seem to think of a counterexample.

I think you're right to feel that way.

Consider the free $F_2$ algebra (where $F_2$ is the field of two elements) $F_2\langle x,y\rangle$. Keep in mind that $x$ and $y$ are two indeterminates that do not commute.

We'll say that the "degree" of a polynomial in this algebra is the largest total of exponents of a monomial with nonzero coefficient. So, for example, the degree of $xyxy+x^2y^2x$ is $5$. Clearly if $a,b$ are in the algebra and $deg(b)>0$, then $deg(ab)>deg(a)$. Using this observation, we can see that the idempotents have to have degree $0$, and so the only ones are $\{0,1\}$. (Alternatively, this ring is a domain, so the only idempotents are $\{0,1\}$.)

However, this algebra is not commutative.

Comment: I assume that in this algebra, $1+1=0$?

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic Yes because as I said, $F_2$ is the field of two elements. That means the ring has characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 5):

As $1$ is idempotent, so is $2:=1+1$. Hence $4=2$ and $2=0$.
Consequently
$$ x+x=2\cdot x=0\cdot x=0$$
for all $x\in R$.

If $x,y$ are idempotent, then so is their sum, hence
$$ x+y=(x+y)^2=x^2+xy+yx+y^2=x+y+xy+yx$$
and using the above, $$xy=-yx= yx.$$
Then also $(xy)^2=xyxy=xxyy=x^2y^2$, i.e., we see that the idempotents are not only closed under addition (and, as $-1=1$, under subtraction), but also under multiplication, i.e., they form a subring $S$ of $R$. Also, $S$ is abelian. Can we show $S=R$ from this?

Comment: I don't think so, because the only thing that's known about an arbitrary element $x$ of $R$ is that $2x=0$, so there's no reason for $x^2$ to have any constraints.